# Adding rows dynamically in a table in C# while populating data from sqlserver

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am retrieving data from sqlserver using Dropdown list box selected value and storing it in 
an arraylist. Now the problem is how to retieve the arraylist values and display in the table.

Comment: Why are you using `ArrayList`? The year is 2014.

Comment: Why are you still using `ArrayList` in 2014? use generic lists.

Comment: By asp.net you mean mvc or web forms?

Comment: @gleng i already have array list code which displays value in <div> tag.

Comment: @szpic i am working in website

Answer (score 0):

Use it like below

```
    ArrayList myArrayList = new ArrayList();

    //Fill ArrayList values from the SQL Server
    myArrayList.Add("Hello");
    myArrayList.Add("World");

    Table table = new Table();

    foreach (var item in myArrayList)
    {
        TableRow tr = new TableRow();
        TableCell tc = new TableCell();

        //Add Arraylist item into TableCell to display it
        tc.Text = item.ToString();

        tr.Cells.Add(tc);

        table.Rows.Add(tr);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using asp.net mvc you can use something like this:

```
<table>
    @foreach (var item in List) {
    <tr>
        <td>
           item.somethingA
        </td>
        <td>
           item.somethingB
        </td>

    </tr>
}
</table>
```

etc to create table